# Как исправить ошибку валидации «The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead»?

Tags: валидация, recaptcha

Есть сайт на Joomla и Wordpress. Нужно исправить ошибки валидации. Почти все исправил кроме 2 ошибок:

1) The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

2) No p element in scope but a p end tag seen.

Обе ошибки возникают из-за reCaptcha.
А reCaptcha вызывается в: Wordpress - Contact Form 7, Joomla - RSForm Pro.
Как можно исправить эти ошибки?

Ссылка на валидатор:
https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fkupit-spravku.org%2Fprices%2Fspravka-o-vremennoj-netrudosposobnosti-uchashchegosya-forma-095-u